# troubles creating a List of doubles from a list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

i have a list with objects. The object has a property 'Sales' which is a string.
Now i want to create a list of doubles with the values of all objects' 'Sales' properties.

I tried this:
var tmp = from n in e.Result select new{ Convert.ToDouble ( n.Sales) };

but this gives me this error:

Error   106 Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

EDIT: first i tried it without the Convert, but then i have  a list of anonymous types (not strings) and i couldn't get that converted to a list fo doubles either....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
var tmp = from n in e.Result select new{Value = Convert.ToDouble ( n.Sales) };
```

You need to define a property name for the anon type: i.e. "Value = *blah*"

Answer (score 4):

The following will give you a list of doubles.

```
List<double> listOfDoubles = (from n in e.Result
                              select Convert.ToDouble(n.Sales)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var tmp = from n in e.Result select new{ Sales = Convert.ToDouble ( n.Sales) };
```